# Java Play Form Submission

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using the Play 2.6 Java forms example.  It has a simple Widget.java model and a WidgetData.java class which is a form processing DTO that maps to the widget form (I don't quite get it).

The example works but need a better explanation of what is happening in the controllers.  Here's the controller method in question:

```
public class WidgetController extends Controller {

    private final Form<WidgetData> form;
    private final List<Widget> widgets;

    @Inject
    public WidgetController(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.form = formFactory.form(WidgetData.class);
        this.widgets = com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList();
    }


    public Result createWidget() {
        final Form<WidgetData> boundForm = form.bindFromRequest(); #1

        WidgetData data = boundForm.get();                         #2
        widgets.add(new Widget(data.getName(), data.getPrice()));

        return redirect(routes.WidgetController.listWidgets());
    }
}
```

I numbered the lines that confuse me.

What is happening in #1?  What's being created from form to boundForm since they are both of the same type?  The WidgetData setter methods are being set here.

So if the WidgetData properties are already set what is happening in #2?  Is it that the properties are set but we need an actual WidgetData object to create the Widget model from?

Hard to nail all this down as examples and docs for versions 2.0 - 2.6 contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

So the first line

```
final Form<WidgetData> boundForm = form.bindFromRequest();
```

gets all submitted values from the request, and tries to map it on the form which will contain a WidgetData Object. The Form is just a wrapper needed for this process.
The data is also validated here.

If you debug your application and take a look on the Form-Object you'll see a map containing the raw submitted data and another one containing validation errors.

Then

```
WidgetData data = boundForm.get();
```

will extract the WidgetData object from the Wrapper Form. This only works if the validation was successful.

hope this helps you a little bit.